# Asynchronous MVC4 action seems to block multiple requests received at the same time

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to make my MVC controller action run asynchronously under .NET 4.0. However, none of my attempts have given me the results I want. I have the following action:

```
public ActionResult ImportXml()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_importRunning)
                return Content("Already running");

            var obj = new object();
            lock (obj)
            {
                _importRunning = true;
                Thread.Sleep(20000);
                //_employesImportService.ImportXml();
                _importRunning = false;
            }

            return Content("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Content(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

When I run two browsers simultaneously that call this action, both seem to wait the 20 seconds I set in the Thread.Sleep(20000). I though that using the lock mechanism would block one request and return the "Already running" content immediately. I'm using .NET 4.0 and I don't have the option of using async await. But is there another way of implementing this so that one of the requests responds quickly?

Comment: Your `lock` is meaningless.

Comment: You probably need to disable session state.

Comment: I understand now why the lock is meaningless but when I try to disable session state, both requests still take 20 seconds to respond. There's obviously something I'm not getting.

Comment: Pause the debugger while the second request is waiting and see what its thread is doing.

Comment: I tried to use the Threads pane in Visual Studio to understand what the second thread is doing but can't seem to figure it out. No matter what, the second thread waits too. I tried setting a static object, I tried Monitor.TryEnter, etc, but no success. The second thread does not respond immediately with message "Already running".

Comment: What's the call stack for each thread?

Comment: Both threads have the same call stack, two lines, the call to my action and [External Code]. I'm not 100% sure of the wording on the second one, from  memory.

Comment: Disable `Just My Code` in debugger options and you'll see where they're actually stuck.